# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

As soon as I add this line

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
```

I am getting this error

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/modulerr?p0=mctApp&p1=Error%3A…rg%2F1.2.16%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DmctApp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%2...<omitted>...1)
```

I have added these scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/lib/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
```

Javascript app code

```
angular.module('myApp', []).config(mctRouter);

function mctRouter($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'home.jsp'
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to inject `ngRoute` to your app. Inject it like

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']).config(mctRouter);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$route, $routeParams and ngView` have been pulled from core angular.js
to angular-route.js/ngRoute module. Hence, you'll now need to load
angular-route.js file and define dependency on ngRoute module.

i.e.

Before:

```
<script src="angular.js"></script>
.....
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['someOtherModule']);
```

After:

```
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="angular-route.js"></script>
.....
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'someOtherModule']);
```

More details [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/5599b55b04788c2e327d7551a4a699d75516dd21)