# AngularJs injector error

Tags: angularjs

I've followed this [direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212692/uncaught-error-injectormodulerr-http-errors-angularjs-org-1-2-16/23880223#23880223) already; however, it doesn't seem to resolve my issue. I am always getting this error after using $resource.

here's the full exception:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/modulerr?
```

here's a snippet from my app.js

```
angular.module('ffApp', [
'ffApp.services',
'ffApp.controllers',
'ngRoute',
'ngResource'
])
```

Any idea what else is causing this?

Comment: Can we see which libraries you included

Comment: Have you included all the libraries, just mentioning them as dependencies won't work.

Comment: It seems some of modules are unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working already. It turned out I needed both angular-resource.min.js and angular-route.min.js

Thanks for looking!